# How to assign input text values into an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a table, certain input text fields are displayed. Accordingly data could be inputted in it. My intention is to club all the input data into an array. Each record has its specific unique id, which we get in console while we input in text box. Based on this id, I want to club into an array data. I've tried with one logic but gives error. Please have a look at the code below

```
// Here newData is an array of records which I'm displaying in Grid
const [dataNew, setDataNew] = useState(newData);

const textChange = (data) => {
    const { id, value } = data;
    setDataNew((prevInfo) => {
      const dataIndex = +id[id.length - 1];
      return {
        ...prevInfo,
         
        // Here I'm getting error in the below code snippet in prevInfo
        dataHere: Object.assign([...prevInfo.newData], { [dataIndex]: value })
      };
    });
  };

console.log('NEW DATA', newData)
```

Please suggest me if any changes to be done. Any solution highly appreciated

Please refer codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-varahamihira-xpjtdb?file=/src/Table.js:149-197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataNew` is initially an array, but you are returning an object from the `setDataNew` callback.

Also `id` is a number itself in your sandbox, so the following would suffice:

```js
const textChange = (data) => {
  const { id, value } = data;
  setDataNew((prevInfo) => {
    const dataIndex = id - 1;
    prevInfo[dataIndex] = value;
    return [...prevInfo];
  });
};
```

Comment: Perfect answer, as expected. Thanks

Comment: One issue I had... what if id is changed... as I've done it and getting undefined... can you please help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73764649/getting-undefined-when-adding-input-text-values-into-array