# Getting undefined when adding input text values into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I'm displaying certain records in a table which also has input text boxes for changing the values when needed. To process those changed records it needs to be added into an array, but, getting undefined when changed the values. Although each record is associated with unique id, unable to add in new array. Please refer to the code below.

```
const textChange = (data) => {
    const { id, value } = data;

    setDataNew((prevInfo) => {

      // Here the records are getting undefined and not getting added into array
      const dataIndex = id - 1;
      prevInfo[dataIndex] = value;
      return [...prevInfo];
    });
  };
```

Any suggestions and solution highly appreciated.

Please refer to code sandbox link for better clarity --> https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-varahamihira-xpjtdb?file=/src/Table.js:757-959

Comment: what is your need ?

Comment: I want to add input text values in an array, with its unique id as its index... which can be seen in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly here is what you need to do if you need all the records which got updated :

```
  const textChange = (data) => {
    const { id, value } = data;
    setDataNew((prevInfo) => {
      const newList = [...prevInfo];
      const index = newList.findIndex((datum) => datum.id === id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        newList[index] = { id, value };
      } else {
        newList.push({ id, value });
      }
      return [...newList];
    });
  };
```

> Mistake in your code

You were getting `undefined` because you were calculating index like :

```
 const dataIndex = id - 1;
```

if the changed object id was `6708` , you were adding element at `6707th` index. Hence all first `6706` element were showing up as `undefined`.
[image: console]

Link : [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/trusting-butterfly-v4jv8x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Perfect.... this is the expected answer... Thanks

Comment: Hello... can you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73768945/getting-undefined-when-inputted-data-in-multiple-fields the issue is when input text is changed date data is undefined.... and it happens vice-versa